# Broadcast receiver in Android Studio

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, battery, batterylevel

**How to solve this on Android Studio in Java Language?**

You have to make two applications that:

**The First app is broadcast receiver
The second app is twit broadcast app**

And you should show us:

broadcast in the same app: create a broadcast receiver to popup a notification when the phone power is lower than 4%
broadcast from first app to second app:
-Create button to start a service and show a toast that service started
-Create button to stop a the service and show a toast that service stopped
-Create button to send a message notification 'hello AMD Class ' from this app to the second app

## What I did

[Added these lines in Manifest XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbXzw.png)
[Added these lines in Manifest XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0SJZ.png)

[Created Java Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYc3o.png)